# С чего начать решать задачу сортировки элементов массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

С чего начать решать эту задачу?

> По результатам опроса прошлого года известен список 10 политических деятелей в порядке убывания их популярности. Проведен новый опрос. Каждый из N журналистов (N - заданное число) назвал три различные фамилии из этого списка. Требуется получить новый список в порядке убывания популярности политических деятелей и показать место, которое занимал каждый деятель в предыдущем опросе. Предусмотреть проверку: каждый их опрошенных журналистов называл разные фамилии и только из имеющихся в старом списке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, нам нужно определить, какие данные о политиках нужно хранить. Исходя из задачи, это фамилия (строка или массив символов), место в предыдущем рейтинге и текущий рейтинг. Такие данные удобнее всего хранить в структуре (ради всего святого, не пишите класс "Политик", это процедурная задача и ООП здесь не место). Место в предыдущем рейтинге рейтинге присваивается исходя из порядка чтения фамилий. Текущий рейтинг изначально у всех политиков равен 0. Всех политиков складываем в массив. Теперь журналисты. Читаем с консоли/из файла мнения журналистов. Временно сохраняем все три менеия каждого журналиста, чтобы сравнить их между собой. Если среди них есть повторяющиеся, выводим сообщение об этом и пропускаем этого журналиста. Если повторов нет, ищем фамилии в списке политиков. Если нашли - добавляем 1 к текущему рейтингу. Если фамилии нет в списке, выводим соответствующее сообщение. Вот мы обработали мнения всех журналистов, теперь у каждого политика есть новый рейтинг. Теперь нужно их отсортировать по этому рейтингу. Проще всего это сдедать [методом пузырька](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC). Не забываем, что политик у нас - структура, сравнивать нужно только нужное нам поле, а менять местами всю структуру. Всё, теперь осталось только вывести результат. Всё что нужно (фамилии и места в предыдущем рейтинге) мы сохранили, поэтому остальное - дело техники.

Решение задачи можно сильно упростить, если использовать [векторы](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) вместо массивов. Тогда не придётся заморачиваться выделением памяти. Также, для векторов определена функция [сортировки](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), так что её тоже можно не писать. Только не забывайте, что мы сортируем структуры, так что придётся написать компаратор для двух структур и передать его в функцию sort.

Answer (score 1):

с [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)